# shell $ character overwrites the previous variable

Tags: shell, sh, freebsd

I'm trying to write a script on shell but I'm stucked on a point.

I have a program creating data daily and puting it to a directory like this: `home/meee/data/2013/07/22/mydata`

My problem is I'm trying to change directory using date. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

x=$(date -u -v-2H "+%Y-%m-%d")
echo $x
year=$(echo $x | cut -d"-" -f1)
month=$(echo $x | cut -d"-" -f2)
day=$(echo $x | cut -d"-" -f3)
echo $year
echo $month
echo $day

d1='/home/sensor/data/'${year}/${month}
echo $d1
```

There is no problem related to `year, day, month`, they are working. But the output of `echo d1` is `/07me/sensor/data/2013`. Similarly, when I write `echo $year$day` it gives `2312 (characters of day is overwritten on the first two characater of the year)`

I tried many other syntax like instead of `'` character put `"` or leave it empty. Removing `{` and so on. But nothing changed.

**Shortly, when I write two variable `($var1 $var2)` in same line the second `$` behaves like go to the beginning of the line and start overwriting the first variable.**

I've been looking for that but there is nothing related to that or I couldn't find anything related and there are a lot of solution in Stackoverflow that solves the problem using `$var1$var2`

What am I doing wrong, or how can I solve that.

I'm working on **FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE amd64** and using **sh**

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I tried the same code ( with removing that -v-2H option for date) `sagar.sakre@sagar-vm $ ./temp.sh 
2013-07-23
2013
07
23
./data/2013/07`

Comment: Post your current output

Comment: my output is `/07ta/2013/`. I think it is because of version of `sh`

Comment: yeah, check with `bash`

Answer (score 2):

Somehow, your commands are introducing carriage returns to your variables, which affect the output when the variable is not the last thing `echo`ed. You can confirm this by passing the value through `hexdump` or `od`:

```
printf "%s" "$x" | hexdump -C   # Look for 0d in the output.
printf "%s" "$year" | hexdump -C   # Look for 0d in the output.
printf "%s" "$month" | hexdump -C   # Look for 0d in the output.
printf "%s" "$day" | hexdump -C   # Look for 0d in the output.
```

---

I don't think this will fix the problem, but you can get the year, month, and day without forking so many external programs:

```
IFS=- read year month day <<EOF
$(date -u -v-2H "+%Y-%m-%d")
EOF
```

or more simply

```
read year month day <<EOF
$(date -u -v-2H "+%Y %m %d")
EOF
```

Comment: I dont have problem related with getting year, month and date. Could you, please clarify the first part?

Answer (score 0):

You’re likely using MinGW or some other not-quite-Unix environment for Windows®, which is introducing Carriage Return (CR, \r) characters at end-of-line (from the Unix PoV).

So change this to either:

```
x=$(date -u -v-2H "+%Y-%m-%d" | sed $'s/\r$//')
echo $x
year=$(echo $x | cut -d"-" -f1 | sed $'s/\r$//')
month=$(echo $x | cut -d"-" -f2 | sed $'s/\r$//')
day=$(echo $x | cut -d"-" -f3 | sed $'s/\r$//')
```

Or, even better:

```
x=$(date -u -v-2H "+%Y %m %d ")
echo $x
set -- $x
year=$1
month=$2
day=$3
```

Note the extra space after %d which ensures that the CR will become $4 instead of attached to the day.

Comment: I'm using sh in FreeBSD 9.0 not MinGW. I don't get how will this help me solve the problem. My problem is when I write `$a$b` b is written on a. For instance, `a = qqqqq, b = www, $a$b results wwwqq`. I dont have the BSD machine with me now, when I got it tomorrow I will try these methods.

Comment: @smttsp: the carriage return at the end of `$a` causes the cursor to move to the beginning of the line before printing the value of `$b`, causing the overlap you observe. If you can figure out how the carriage return is added, you can prevent it to solve your problem.

Comment: Are you, by chance, using an editor that adds CR to the end of line, on your FreeBSD system then? That would certainly be an issue.

Comment: Try putting it all into one line (after the #!/bin/sh): x=$(date -u -v-2H "+%Y-%m-%d"); echo $x; year=$(echo $x | cut -d"-" -f1); month=$(echo $x | cut -d"-" -f2); day=$(echo $x | cut -d"-" -f3); echo $year; echo $month; echo $day; d1='/home/sensor/data/'${year}/${month}; 
echo $d1; # comment at end of line